# Appropriate way to send individual Welcome Emails via the API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, php

Currently, I have a Welcome Email solution (PHP) that works via the ExactTarget API.
However, it's a little messy and is causing issues within the ET user interface.

Basically, upon registering for the site, I create an email object and trigger a send using the address the user just registered with. The email is sent with a nice, "Dear *username* ," intro and an entry is created inside of ExactTarget to show the results of the send.

So the Welcome email is being created and sent just fine!

**The issue** though is that I have hundreds of new users a day. Which means each week, the folder inside of the ExactTarget admin interface has 1,000 new "sent" email entries in it. There are now many thousand entries and basically the folder never loads. I have to refresh the entire admin interface and avoid that folder or else it gets stuck loading all the entries.

It's only going to get worse from here and I read that the defaul ET "Welcome Email" solution does not work for API calls.

What would be the best way to get around this?
Is it possible to create a temporary list that I can add users to? This way I can perform ONE single send to the list and then delete the list altogether. (Would this still allow me to greet users by name in the email?)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're creating a new email for every time.  You should only need to create a single TriggeredSendDefinition in ET and then fire it off using the API.  The results should only increment the counter in Interactions > Triggered Emails.

[Here's](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/) more information about sending a Triggered Send Email via API.

Comment: This sounds exactly how I _should_ be doing this.  
Basically the path my calls are taking:  
1) create email object  
2) create triggeredSendDefinition  
3) activate the triggeredSend (created in step2)  
4) perform triggeredSend  
  
Sounds like I don't need to do steps 2 and 3, since the triggeredSend has already been created once.  
  
How exactly do I go about passing the sendDefinition the new email object on the second go around?

Comment: If you look at the example on the page I linked to, you just need to reference the TriggeredSendDefinition's CustomerKey -- then pass along all of the subscriber attributes.  Ignore the first and last examples on that page -- they're passing along the body of an email to the TSD, which I think is confusing.  The PHP example is more typical.